# Converting object to array or keeping an array with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have an input file which type may vary from array to object, one of the following inputs expected:

```
[{"version": "1.0"}]
{version: "1.0"}
```

How can I construct jq expression for the output to be always converted into array. I came up with the following:

```
jq 'if (select(has("version")?)) then [.] else . end'
```

once `version` key is matched, object is added inside array, but if not matched, that would mean it's already an array, nothing is printed, and I would it expect it to be printed as it is. Please suggest the right way to achieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the input's `type` directly:

```sh
jq 'if type == "object" then [.] else . end'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FLmNOB3DNS)

---

Or use the deconstruction alternative operator `?//` (available since [jq 1.6](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6)):

```sh
jq '. as [$v] ?// $v | [$v]'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ox13HMlbOe)

Answer (score 1):

Auxiliary to pmf's answer, why doesn't this work?

`input.jsonl`:

```
[{"version": "1.0"}]
{"version": "2.0"}
```

Command:

```
jq -c 'if (select(has("version")?)) then [.] else . end'
```

Actual output:

```
[{"version": "2.0"}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{"version": "1.0"}]
[{"version": "2.0"}]
```

First of all, `select` filters out values. For each value input to `select`, it evaluates the filter you give it on its input, and if that filter evaluates to a true value, the whole input value it emitted unchanged. Otherwise there is no output. Using `select` here is unhelpful, because you want a true or false value for the `if` condition. If the condition part of your `if-then-else` expression emits no output then the whole `if-then-else` expression emits no output.

A more thorough way to understand `select(expr)` is that every time `expr` emits a true value then the `select(expr)` emits its input value. A more thorough way to understand `if cond then a else b end` is that every time `cond` emits a true value the whole `if-then-else` emits `a` and every time `cond` emits a false value the whole `if-then-else` emits `b`.

Okay, so forget the `select`... why doesn't this work?

Command:

```
jq -c 'if (has("version")?) then [.] else . end'
```

Actual output:

```
[{"version": "2.0"}]
```

In this case, the `?` is the [error suppression operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ErrorSuppression%2FOptionalOperator%3A%3F) and is equivalent to `try has("version")` which is itself equivalent to `try has("version") catch empty`. This means that when an error occurs the expression returns `empty` which means no output. An error does indeed occur when the input is a list instead of an object. When the condition part of the `if-then-else` expression emits no output, you guessed it, the whole expression emits no output.

You could make this work by doing this instead:

Command:

```
jq -c 'if (try has("version") catch false) then [.] else . end'
```

Actual output:

```
[{"version":"1.0"}]
[{"version":"2.0"}]
```

Of course that's a bit roundabout. You should follow pmf's answer. But this perhaps helps you understand why your attempt didn't go as you expected.

As a rule of thumb, try to make sure your `select` and `if` conditions always emit exactly one output for each input - that way you will not be surprised. Expressions that can emit zero outputs (e.g. `expr?` or `select(...)`) or multiple outputs (e.g. `.[]`) will make for a confusing time when used as conditions in `select` or `if`.

Answer (score 0):

The `arrays` function selects an input if it is an array. Combined with `//` you can handle the case where it isn't:

```sh
$ jq -c 'arrays // [.]' versions.json 
[{"version":"1.0"}]
[{"version":"2.0"}]
```

---

Where `versions.json` is:

```json
[{"version":"1.0"}]
{"version":"2.0"}
```